# Elasticsearch two level sort in aggregation list

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Currently I am sorting aggregations by document score, so most relevant items come first in aggregation list like below:

```
{
            'aggs' : {
                'guilds' : {
                    'terms' : {
                        'field' : 'guilds.title.original',
                        'order' : [{'max_score' : 'desc'}],
                        'aggs' : {
                            'max_score' : {
                                'script' : 'doc.score'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to add another sort option to the order terms order array in my JSON. but when I do that like this :

```
{
        'order' : [{'max_score' : 'desc'}, {"_count" : "desc"},
    }
```

The second sort does not work. For example when all of the scores are equal it then should sort based on query but it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a correction to Andrei's answer ... to order aggregations by multiple criteria, you **MUST** create an array as shown in [Terms Aggregation: Order](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) and you **MUST** be using ElasticSearch 1.5 or later.

So, for Andrei's answer, the correction is:
`"order" : [ { "max_score": "desc" }, { "_count": "desc" } ]`

As Andrei has it, ES will not complain but it will **ONLY** use the last item listed in the "order" element.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how your 'aggs' is even working because I tried it and I had parsing errors in three places: "order" is not allowed to have that array structure, your second "aggs" should be placed outside the first "terms" aggs and, finally, the "max_score" aggs should have had a "max" type of "aggs". In my case, to make it work (and it does actually order properly), it should look like this:

```
  "aggs": {
    "guilds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "guilds.title.original",
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc", 
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "doc.score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Andrei - in trying what you suggest above, I've found that ES simply performs the ordering based on the last item in the "order" element.  For my scenario, I want to order on a "rank" field (in which there will be "ties" among terms) which I then want to sub-sort within those by the best average doc scores.  Whichever of those two "orders" I specify last is what it used.  I don't see any way to sub-order terms.

Comment: @ThomasDoman : I have the exact same issue-the ordering happens on the basis of the last item in the rder list. Did you find a solution to the problem? Thanks !

Comment: @UD1989 - I sure did, my answer is below in the form of a correction to Andrei's answer.  Be sure to upvote it, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasDoman : Thanks. Unfortunately our elasticsearch is a  hosted application and runs on version 1.3.4 *sigh*